# How to update textLabel inside a tableview cell iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a table view programatically, below is the code, when I tried to update the label using a completion handler the value is not displayed in the table view cell.

Could someone please suggest me how I could update the textLabel in the **languagesSpokenCell** in my tableview ? I have spent several hours trying to get this resolved, but I am still unable to.

Here is the completion Handler that is called after the user selects the languages that he speaks.

```
func showLanguagesSpoken(_ languagesSpoken: [String]?){
        languagesSpokenString = (languagesSpoken?.joined(separator: ", "))!
        languagesSpokenCell.textLabel?.text = languagesSpokenString
       //*** In the below print statement the value is printed correctly but the text label is not updated in the cell. 
        print("languagesSpokenCell.textLabel?.text: \(languagesSpokenCell.textLabel?.text)") 
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

Here I am Programatically creating table view cells

```
// FOR TABLE VIEW - Tableview cells
    var tableView: UITableView  =   UITableView()

    var firstNameCell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell()
    var lastNameCell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell()
    var languagesSpokenCell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell()
    
    
    // FOR TABLE VIEW - Textfields
    var firstName: UITextField = UITextField()
    var lastName: UITextField = UITextField()



override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        
        // construct first name cell, section 0, row 0
        self.firstNameCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.5)
        self.firstName = UITextField(frame: self.firstNameCell.contentView.bounds.insetBy(dx: 15, dy: 0))
        self.firstName.placeholder = "First Name"
        self.firstNameCell.addSubview(self.firstName)
        
        // construct last name cell, section 0, row 1
        self.lastNameCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.5)
        self.lastName = UITextField(frame: self.lastNameCell.contentView.bounds.insetBy(dx: 15, dy: 0))
        self.lastName.placeholder = "Last Name"
        self.lastNameCell.addSubview(self.lastName)
        
        self.languagesSpokenCell.textLabel?.text = "Languages Spoken"
        self.languagesSpokenCell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.5)
        self.languagesSpokenCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.disclosureIndicator
  
    }
```

Below are the Table view methods

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    // Return the number of rows for each section in your static table
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch(section) {
        case 0: return 2    // section 0 has 2 rows
        case 1: return 1    // section 1 has 1 row
        default: fatalError("Unknown number of sections")
        }
    }

    // Return the row for the corresponding section and row

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch(indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            switch(indexPath.row) {
            case 0: return self.firstNameCell   // section 0, row 0 is the first name
            case 1: return self.lastNameCell    // section 0, row 1 is the last name
            default: fatalError("Unknown row in section 0")
            }
        case 1:
            switch(indexPath.row) {
            case 0: return self.languagesSpokenCell
            }
        default: fatalError("Unknown section")
        }
    }

    // Customize the section headings for each section
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        switch(section) {
        case 0: return "Profile"
        case 1: return "Languages Spoken"
        default: fatalError("Unknown section")
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let row     = indexPath.row
        let section = indexPath.section

        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell


       if section == 4 && row == 0 {
            // The user has clicked on languages spoken cell
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showLanguageSelectionTVC", sender: self)
        }

        print("Printing celll text label: \(currentCell.textLabel!.text)")

    }
```

Below are the constraints that I have set in the `ViewDidLoad()` method.

```
    tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect.zero, style: UITableViewStyle.grouped)
    tableView.delegate      =   self
    tableView.dataSource    =   self
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)

    // Disabling automatic constraints

    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints                     = false

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let viewDict = [
        "tableView"                 : tableView
    ]


    // Setting Constraints for the table view
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[tableView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewDict))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[tableView]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: viewDict))
```

Comment: Try reloading the tableview in main thread.

Comment: after your reload tableview, did the `tableView(_ tableView:cellForRowAt indexPath:)` method be called?

Comment: which place you are calling the `showLanguagesSpoken()`

Comment: @ovo after reloading the tableView with `self.tableView.reloadData()` , the method `tableView(_ tableView:cellForRowAt indexPath:)` is NOT called.

Comment: @ebby94 tried to reload the tableView in the main method by using  `DispatchQueue.main.async` but it still doesn't update the cell.

Comment: Do you check tableview datasource have been set?

Comment: @ovo it has been set in the `viewDidLoad()` method  using `tableView.delegate      =   self` & `tableView.dataSource    =   self` you can see it in my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

To update any cell in tableview you need to reload it. You can reload it per cell or or specific cells or whole tableview. Before reloading tableview make sure that you update your datasource.

In this `showLanguagesSpoken` method you are trying to change the text of cell without updating the tableView.

Also make sure you always changes the data in `cellForRowAtIndexpath`

Answer (score 0):

Remove reloadData from following method.

```
func showLanguagesSpoken(_ languagesSpoken: [String]?){
        languagesSpokenString = (languagesSpoken?.joined(separator: ", "))!
        languagesSpokenCell.textLabel?.text = languagesSpokenString
       //*** In the below print statement the value is printed correctly but the text label is not updated in the cell. 
        print("languagesSpokenCell.textLabel?.text: \(languagesSpokenCell.textLabel?.text)") 
        }
```

Comment: Tried by removing `reloadData` as well, but it still doesn't update.

Answer (score 0):

Label `languagesSpokenCell.textLabel` text update process should be on **main thread**.

```
func showLanguagesSpoken(_ languagesSpoken: [String]?) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        languagesSpokenString = (languagesSpoken?.joined(separator: ", "))!

        languagesSpokenCell.textLabel?.text = languagesSpokenString

        print("languagesSpokenCell.textLabel?.text: \(languagesSpokenCell.textLabel?.text)")
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but it still doesn't update the text label.

Comment: try this `tableView.beginUpdates()
        languagesSpokenCell.textLabel?.text = languagesSpokenString
        tableView.endUpdates()`

Comment: is that cell is visible in your table view? Because you are allocating cell but not setting frame for the `UITableViewCell`

Comment: Tried with begin and endUpdates methods, but it still doesn't update the cell. I am updating my question with the constraints that I've used.